# accesscheck.php and My_Session.php creates different session_id

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

I use codeigniter and I'm new on CodeIgniter. So, I should make silly mistakes, sorry for that.

When I try to control session_id from accesscheck.php to log in user panel, I see that MY_Session.php sesison_id different from accesscheck.php.

I don't know how to fix it. Is there anyone that knows what should i do?

[image]

Comment: post your code or error to solve your problem.

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin which pages code do you want to see? there is no error message just my codes creates session_id twice time.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-regenerate-id.php is the key - thats what CI does...

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it with updating memcached.exe . It works like a charm. Thanks for comments.